# Windows System Server Running on Port 80

Tags: windows, networking

I have IIS and Apache servers installed on my Vista OS, I have Stopped All of these servers but localhost still working , when I try  connecting to localhost I got 404 error page. I found the port 80 is bounded to PID 4 to the System Process. there is no clear individual  service working on this port . This is what I get through command line:

Active Connections

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID

  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       980

  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3992

  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

As you can see this process is opening 3 `ports 80,445 and 5357` , I think this is some related to asp.net or sqlexpress but not sure .

anyone has a proper solution to this problem ?? how to release port 80 and what service is running on this port ??

Comment: how do youu produce this output? try netstat -nab

Comment: I get this Message when I asked about the Owner Process: "Can not obtain ownership information"

Comment: Are you running it in elevated mode?  I.e. right click on command prompt and select "run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

445 is the SMB port. You might have file sharing enabled which might cause this port to be open. Try disabling file sharing and network discovery.

Comment: Yes 445 is the smb , but no file sharing exist or netbios enabled (135), how could a system start anonymous server on my system ?